# R kableExtra with header expression

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

given the following reproducible example

````
---
title: "test kable"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r}

mydf <- data.frame(a=1:3, b = letters[1:3])

mydf |> 
knitr::kable(col.names = c("A", "B")) |> 
#kableExtra::add_header_above(c("title" = 2)) |> # this is working fine
kableExtra::add_header_above(c("$\\mu$" = 2)) # but this don't
# here I want to insert a title spanning multiple columns containing an expression
# e.g. something like: expression(paste("PM10 [ ", mu*g~m^-3, " ]"))
```
````

my goal is to insert in a kable header an expression containing some greek symbols (see above);

please also consider I need to have a latex output;

by the way I've also defined inside the Rmarkdown file a new command by:

```
\newcommand{\ugmc}{\si{\micro\gram\per\cubic\meter}}
```

after having inserted
`\usepackage{siunitx}`
inside the preamble of the tex template file (but, this is another story, just mentioned here for framing the full context)

any help pointing me in the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `escape = FALSE` with `\\\\` to insert greek letters like this:

````
---
title: "test kable"
output: pdf_document

---

```{r}
mydf <- data.frame(a=1:3, b = letters[1:3])

mydf |> 
knitr::kable(col.names = c("A", "B"), 'latex') |> 
kableExtra::add_header_above(c("$\\\\beta$" = 2), escape = FALSE) 
```

```{r}
mydf <- data.frame(a=1:3, b = letters[1:3])

mydf |> 
knitr::kable(col.names = c("A", "B"), 'latex') |> 
kableExtra::add_header_above(c("$PM10[\\\\mu*g\\\\sim m^{-3}]$" = 2), escape = FALSE) 
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: ...ummhhh, thank you for your answer but is that rendering correctly? I just get a literal 'mu' but not the corresponding greek letter I need.. and what about the insertion of the expression?

Comment: Hi @maxbre, I updated my answer! You should use `\\\\` in combination with escape to show the greek letters.

Comment: I also added your second expression with multiple greek letters

Answer (score 0):

my final code here

---

````
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r}

mydf <- data.frame(a=1:3, b = letters[1:3])

mydf |> 
knitr::kable(col.names = c("A", "B"), format='latex', escape = FALSE) |> 
kableExtra::add_header_above(c("$\\\\beta$" = 2), escape = FALSE) |>
kableExtra::add_header_above(c("$PM10~[~\\\\mu g~m^{-3}~]$" = 2), escape = FALSE)
```
````